# Running Octave in TextMate

Tags: matlab, octave, textmate

I am trying to use Octave within TextMate. I have installed the appropriate bundles, and have Octave installed. I am able to run Octave from within the Terminal, but would like to run programs from within TextMate itself. When I hit Build and Run, I get an error stating that the directory I am using does not contain an Xcode project, and an attempt to build with Xcode that fails.

My files are in .m format, and I've successfully used TextMate for other programming languages. Does anyone know why I can't get it to run with Octave?

Best,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find this useful:

https://github.com/schoeps/matlab.tmbundle

Eddie

Answer (score 1):

.m is typically used as an file extension for Objective-C source files, so it seems like TextMate interprets it accordingly. You could see if the correct bundle is used and, if neccessary, deactivate the Objective-C bundle.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm pretty sure that it's using the correct Bundle -- I have it selected in the scroll menu on the lower left of the editor. I went ahead and deleted the Objective-C bundle, since I wasn't using it anyways, and it didn't solve my problem. Do you have any additional thoughts? I also read through the TextMate wiki on Bundles, and it didn't provide any additional advice...